# Length error in update statement in q kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table where I want to update few columns of a row based on a condition

```
q)t:([] id:10 20; l1:("Blue hor";"Antop"); l2:("Malad"; "KC"); pcd:("NCD";"FRB") )
```

When I used update statement, it throws 'length error

```
q)update l1:"Chin", l2:"Gor" from t where id=10
'length
q)update l1:"Chin", l2:"Gor" from `t where id=10
'length
```

I read below in `Q for Mortals` but is there any way to update few columns of a row based on a condition?

> The actions in the Where phrase and the Update phrase are vector
>   operations on entire column lists. This is the Zen of update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are dealing with Char-lists here (rather than symbol), you need use enlist:

```
q)update l1:enlist "Chin", l2:enlist "Gor" from t where id=10
id l1      l2    pcd
----------------------
10 "Chin"  "Gor" "NCD"
20 "Antop" "KC"  "FRB"
```

Otherwise you are trying to update a vector of length 1 (`t where id=10`) with a vector of length 4 (`"Chin"`), or 3 (`"Gor"`).

Answer (score 4):

Please try statement below:

```
update l1:count[i]#enlist"Chin", l2:count[i]#enlist"Gor" from t where id=10
```

It works regardless to how many rows are matched to where clause.

On update, length of assigned list should be equal to number of updated rows. `Q` treats `string` as list of characters. This is why, when you assign `"Chin"` to l1, `Q` tries to assign list of length 4, when list of length 1 is expected. This causes `'length` error.

`count[i]#enlist"Chin"` creates list of N repeated values: `("Chin";"Chin";...)`. Where N is number of updated rows. This fixes the issue

Answer (score 2):

To update the table like this, you need to add the enlist keyword:

```
q)update l1:enlist "Chin", l2:enlist "Gor" from t where id=10
id l1      l2    pcd
----------------------
10 "Chin"  "Gor" "NCD"
20 "Antop" "KC"  "FRB"
```

This is because you need to add lists of strings rather than just strings